# How to print dictionary key and values using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}

for items in dict:
    print items
    print value
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over both the key and the value of a dictionary, you can use the `items()` method, or for Python 2.x `iteritems()`

So the code you are looking for will be as followed:

```
d = {'Name' : 'Zara', 'Age' : '7', 'Class' : 'First'}
#dict is a key word, so you shouldn't write a variable to it

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

And if you were to use Python 2.x rather than 3.x, you would use this line in the for loop:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
```

I hope this has answered your question, just next time try to do a little more research, as there is probably another question answering this available.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}

for items in dict:
    print(items)
    print(dict[items])
```

Or if you want a format like, `key:value`, you can do:
`print(items,':', dict[items])`

Comment: Basically, what you were trying to do was loop through every key in the dictionary (you did, `for items in dict:`). You then tried to print out `item` which was the key. Then you tried to do something like `print(value)`. But there exists nothing called `value`. What you can do instead is print the value of that key by using `dict[item]`.
Read: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

```
dict.items()
dict.values()
```